# Access 2007: What does "@" represent for a textbox format?

Tags: ms-access

On a form in Access 2007, there is a Text Box that has:

```
@
```

in the "Format" field under the Format tab.

What does this represent and what does it do? I did not see it mentioned on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff823190.aspx

If it does not represent anything, what would it be doing to a textbox?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A required text character.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa159684(v=office.10).aspx

Comment: Strange, is there any reason it would be truncating large amounts of text then? As soon as I remove that `@` it stops truncating text.

Comment: If you add a format to a memo-type text, it will truncate to 255 characters. Memo type is very fussy.